# Confusion in piecewise function notation

Tags: piecewise-continuity

I am reading a paper that has the following piecewise function:

[image]

I am not sure what the arrows and `+` in the subscript mean here. I am interpreting it as follows, please correct me if this is wrong. It would be great if you kindly direct me to a resource that defines these notations.

### My interpretation:

- $H(t)$ is zero when $t$ is less than or equal to zero and when $t$ is greater than or equal to $\Delta T_p$.
- $H(t)$  *approaches* 1 when $t$ *approaches* any value greater than 0.
- $H(t)$  *approaches* 0 when $t$ *approaches* $\Delta T_p$.

Please correct if my interpretation is wrong. I am sure that I am missing something here, because when $t$ is greater than 0 and less than $\Delta T_p$, $H(t)$  appears to be approaching 1 and zero.

#### Reference

The paper the function is from is:
Svärd, M., Markkula, G., Engström, J., Granum, F. and Bärgman, J., 2017, September. A quantitative driver model of pre-crash brake onset and control. In Proceedings of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society Annual Meeting (Vol. 61, No. 1, pp. 339-343). Sage CA: Los Angeles, CA: SAGE Publications.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: $$\lim_{t\to a+}f(t)$$ means the one-sided limit of $f(t)$ as $t$ approaches $a$ from the right.  Here we have $H(t)\to1$ as $t$ approaches $0$ through positive values.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you!